# Timestamp comes with .0 at the end

Tags: java, string, datetime, spring-mvc, google-visualization

I'm trying to put in some time stamps in a AnnotatedTimeLine (Google Chart), and its req. to be in the Datetime format. 
When I reformat (to Timestamp format) the string that I receive from the class, it gives me this:

> 2013-06-28 10:08:35.0

What I want to do is to remove the .0 at the end. How can I do this?
The code looks like this:

```
    public List<Survey> getAllSurvey(List<Status> statusList) {
    String sqlValues = "SELECT * FROM status WHERE idCategory = (SELECT idCategory FROM category WHERE name = '"
            + statusList.get(0).getCategoryName() + "');";
    List<Survey> survies = new ArrayList<Survey>();
    try {
        List<Map<String, Object>> rows = getJdbcTemplate().queryForList(
                sqlValues);
        for (Map row : rows) {
            Survey survey = new Survey();
            survey.setCategoryName(statusList.get(0).getCategoryName());
            survey.setValue((String) (row.get("value")));
            survey.setUnit((String) row.get("unit"));
            survey.setTimestamp(row.get("timeStamp") + "");
            survies.add(survey);
            System.out.println(survey.toString());
        }
    } catch (BadSqlGrammarException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(sqlValues);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return survies;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use prepared statements to generate SQL queries, **NOT** string concatenation. Your current code is subject to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: No problems, the project is only going to be used locally.

Comment: That is not a reason! Using prepared statements should be a reflex.

Comment: Okay, I will keep that in mind then, I will try to fix it as soon as I can. This is prio though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one line solution

```
survey.setTimestamp(row.get("timeStamp").toString().replaceAll("\\.\\d+", ""));
```

if performance is critical then this solution is better

```
String ts = row.get("timeStamp").toString();
ts = ts.substring(0, str.indexOf('.'));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! the beneath answer works as well, but I think this one is faster and better since I dont have to create a new SimpleDateFormat!

Answer (score 2):

You must convert the timestamp to the dateformat you want in your class. The default string representation of `Timestamp` is including the nanoseconds at the end. If you want to change that you can always do this:

```
    Timestamp t = Your timestamp;
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY.MM.dd HH:mm:ss");
    String s = df.format(t);
```

Comment: For new readers I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` (and also not `Timestamp`). Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Beware of the case of format pattern letters. Please check once more what is the difference between lower case `y` and upper case `Y`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code contains the line `row.get("timeStamp") + ""`, which will effectively call `row.get("timeStamp").toString() + ""`. Assuming the row contains a `java.sql.Timestamp` object, it will return the timestamp formatted like `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.fffffffff`.

If this is not desired, create a [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) object to represent the desired formatting, and then call `SimpleDateFormat#format(row.get("timeStamp"))` to have your value formatted properly.

The [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class describes how to define your date and time patterns. Make sure to create the [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) object only once, since it's relatively expensive to create it. Many people define it as a `private static final` variable so it can be reused many times.

Comment: This one worked as well, but the above answer is faster I believe. If I could take both as answer I would do that :P

Comment: For `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` (Java 8 and up), I used `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.n` as the format string.

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

1. You seem to be mixing up two things that you should try to distinguish: the value of your timestamp and the format of it.
2. You should not wish to use the `Timestamp` class. It is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `OffsetDateTime`, `Instant` or `LocalDatetime` from java.time.
3. Also in your `Survey` class do not keep the timestamp as a `String`. Still use one of the java.time classes mentioned. Only when you need to give string output, format into a string in the desired format. For this purpose, depending on what you need the string for you can probably do better than just avoiding the `.0` at the end.

### Your problem line

The center of your problem is here:

```
        survey.setTimestamp(row.get("timeStamp") + "");
```

You are concatenating a `Timestamp` from the query and a `String`. In order to do this Java converts the `Timestamp` to a `String` too by calling its `toString` method. `Timestamp.toString()` returns a string with at least one decimal on the seconds (and more, up to 9, if there are more non-zero decimals).

### Solution: java.time

A timestamp means (a representation of) a point in time. The best class to use for a point in time is `Instant` from java.time. So in your `Survey` class define timestamp to be an `Instant`.

For a moment I assume that you are stuck with the `List<Map<String,Object>>` that Spring `queryForList()` returns, and that we cannot avoid the timestamp there being a `java.sql.Timestamp`. If so convert the `Timestamp` to an `Instant` as soon as you get hold of it:

```
        survey.setTimestamp(((Timestamp) row.get("timeStamp")).toInstant());
```

With a more modern query tool you can get either an `OffsetDateTime`, an `Instant` or a `LocalDateTIme` directly from your database and avoid the `Timestamp` class completely.

How to format your `Instant` (or other java.time object) into a string for presentation to the user or for interchange with another system depends so much on the context and requirements. Here’s just one simple example:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.MEDIUM);
    String formattedTimestamp = survey.getTimetamp()
            .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
            .format(formatter);
    System.out.println(formattedTimestamp);
```

Example output:

> Sep 13, 2020 2:26:40 PM

The output from the example code will depend not only on time zone, also on locale.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- Questions and answers about using the java.time classes with your SQL database:

  - [Getting the date from a ResultSet for use with java.time classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29773390/getting-the-date-from-a-resultset-for-use-with-java-time-classes)
  - [Best way to Change java.sql.TimeStamp to UTC format in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63054617/best-way-to-change-java-sql-timestamp-to-utc-format-in-java)
- [Documentation of the `JdbcTemplate.queryForList` method that you used](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForList-java.lang.String-)