# Best way to Change java.sql.TimeStamp to UTC format in Java

Tags: java, timestamp

I have tried multiple ways one of them using SimpleDateFromatter and now trying

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
public static String getCorrectTimeFormat(Timestamp time) {
        return time.toInstant().toString();
    }
```

But the problem is which I realized during writing unit test is, the time gets modified.

```
  Timestamp timeStamp = Timestamp.valueOf("2020-07-22 12:26:51.599");
  String res = UserUtil.getCorrectTimeFormat(timeStamp);
  assertThat(res).isEqualTo("2020-07-22T12:26:51.599Z");
```

This never passes as the it auto converts to "2020-07-22T11:26:51.599Z"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It’s best to avoid `jqva.sql.Timestamp` completely. I’ll show you how.
2. The result you got is correct, as I think you have already discovered.

### Get java.time types from your database

Since JDBC 4.2 we can directly get java.time types from a `ResultSet`. If your database value is a `timestamp with time zone` (recommended), for example:

```
    OffsetDateTime odt = rs.getObject(
            "your_timestamp_with_time_zone_column", OffsetDateTime.class);
    String utcString = odt.withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toString();
```

If your database value is a `timestamp` without time zone (not recommended), we can only get a `LocalDateTime` from it, which doesn’t define a point in time. To convert to `Instant` we need to rely on knowing which time zone the database uses. For example:

```
    ZoneId datebaseTimeZone = ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris");
    LocalDateTime ldt = rs.getObject(
            "your_timestamp_column", LocalDateTime.class);
    String utcString = ldt.atZone(datebaseTimeZone)
            .withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)
            .toString();
```

If your database uses UTC, which counts as an offset, it’s better to use `ZoneOffset` than `ZoneId`:

```
    ZoneOffset datebaseOffset = ZoneOffset.UTC;
    LocalDateTime ldt = rs.getObject(
            "your_timestamp_column", LocalDateTime.class);
    String utcString = ldt.atOffset(datebaseOffset).toString();
```

### Your observed result is correct

`java.sql.Timestamp` confusingly prints in the default time zone of the JVM, and `Timestamp.valueOf()` equally confusingly assumes that time zone. So assuming that your time zone is at offset +01:00 at this time of year (such as Great Britain, Ireland, Portugal, Morocco and Tunesia, for example), the conversion from `2020-07-22 12:26:51.599` to `2020-07-22T11:26:51.599Z` is correct.

Comment: Your understanding of the problem I was facing is completely correct. I have updated my db type to "timestamptz", but what are your thoughts on how to retrieve them in hibernate entity class (when I know my timestamp is in UTC).

Comment: Hibernate 5+ supports java.time types, but I am not fully familiar with the details yet. The optimistic attempt is to declare the entity field `Instant`, but otherwise `OffsetDateTime`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use java 8 time ZonedDateTime class :

```
//1 - default pattern
String timeStamp = "2019-03-27T10:15:30";
ZonedDateTime localTimeObj = ZonedDateTime.parse(time);

//2 - specified pattern
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a z");
String timeStamp1 = "2019-03-27 10:15:30 AM";
ZonedDateTime localTimeObj1 = ZonedDateTime.parse(timeStamp1, formatter);

//To get LocalDate from ZonedDateTime
LocalDate localDate = localTimeObj1.toLocalDate()

//To get timestamp from zoneddatetime with utc timezone
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.from(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant());
```

Comment: I got the issue, actually in my db the time was saved in local time zone, anyways your post is quite helpful.