# How to change the formate of TImeStamp in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, timestamp, retrofit

I am having trouble with `post` object in Retrofit.
What I need to do is making the TimeStamp variable to format of

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'
```

However, my TimeStamp generated by my code

```
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(new Date().getTime());
```

gives the format of `2021-07-11T16:53:45.604+00:00` which is converted to `Jul 11, 2021 12:53:44 PM`

I've looked into diverse documents, but cannot find a way to convert it to a different format.

Is there any way to change my TimeStamp variable format to `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'`?

Thanks!

Comment: Which Java version are you using? 1.7 or 1.8?

Comment: @Vishal I am currently using JDK 9

Comment: No, a `Timestamp` hasn’t got, as in cannot have a format. Does this answer your question? [Timestamp comes with .0 at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17545196/timestamp-comes-with-0-at-the-end)

Comment: I’m confused where the formats you mention are coming from. The code you have posted certainly does not give them.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Timestamp`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `Instant` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: I’m not sure the tags and mentions of Retrofit or MySQL are relevant here.

Comment: Retrofit may be, @BasilBourque. It’s nothing I know, but I seem to gather that it works through JSON. Possibly the OP can put an `Instant` instead if the `Timestamp` in the post object and maybe use https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8?

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Convert from troubled legacy class to modern class, then generate text in standard ISO 8601 format.

```
myTimestamp.toInstant().toString()
```

Or capture the current moment in UTC.

```
Instant.now().toString()
```

## Details

A `java.sql.Timestamp` object does not have have a “format”. The `Timestamp` class represents a moment, not text.

You are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

### `java.time.Instant`

If you have a `Timestamp` object in hand, convert to its replacement, `java.time.Instant`. Look to new conversion methods added to the old classes.

```
Instant instant = myTimestamp.toInstant() ;
```

Capture the current moment as seen in UTC, with an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds, using `Instant.now()`.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
```

#### Generating text

Your desired format complies with the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. Those standard formats are used by default in the *java.time* classes when parsing/generating strings.

```
String output = instant.toString() ;  // Generate text in standard ISO 8601 format.
```

And parsing.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2021-07-11T16:53:45.604Z" ) ;
```

---

### `Z` is not decoration

By the way, regarding your formatting pattern, `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'`, ***never*** put single quotes around the `Z`. The `Z` represents vital information, the offset-from-UTC. Your quotes kill that, turning it into a mere string literal.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 7, you can refer `SimpleDateFormat` to format the date as shown below

```
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(new Date().getTime());
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
String format = simpleDateFormat.format(timestamp);
System.out.println(format);
```

Comment: The OP is using Java 9. And the `SimpleDateFormat` class is a notorious troublemaker of a class and long outdated.

Comment: @Ole Yeah, the solution was intended for 1.7

Comment: For Java 6 and Java 7, use the back-port of the *java.time* classes found in the *ThreeTen-Backport* library. Never use the tragically flawed legacy classes `Timestamp`, `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date`, `Calendar`, etc.